# Aligning text to right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, text, alignment

In the picture shown below, I want to align the starting of two line to the right where exactly the numbering starts. I used \hspace{} command but it is not working. How can I fix this problem??

Thanks for your help in advance.

This is the code is used:-
1. Automatic:- \ 
\hspace{5mm} At first a course transformation is applied by the FSI Mapper followed by a fine transformation on the source mesh to move it closer[image] to the target mesh location.\

Comment: You're probably doing it wrong. You should consider using a list like `enumerate`: `\begin{enumerate} \item Automatic:- \par At first a course ... \end{enumerate}`.

Comment: Please show us the code you're as a MWE:  ie. something we can compile so we can try to duplicate your results.  A MWE will start with `\documentclass` and include `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`

Comment: You can use the `{}` button to properly format your code.  "Right align" usually means to push everything as far as possible to the right, so that "mesh location" ends up at the right margin.  It sounds like you instead want to increase the left margin instead.

Comment: Also, `\hspace{<dim>}` at the beginning of a line will have no effect.  To force the effect, use `\hspace*{<dim>}` instead.

Comment: I don't want to use \begin{enumerate} option.

Comment: I used \hspace*{<dim>} it worked out. But again the next line is not aligned properly.

Comment: If one answer solves your problem please mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what about the `\noindent` command ?

```
\documentclass[]{article}


    \begin{document}
    \noindent
    1. Automatic:-\\
        At first a course transformation is applied by the FSI Mapper followed by a fine transformation on the source mesh to move it closer


    \end{document}
```

Comment: no problem. It worked out with \begin{enumerate} syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Werner, you may consider using `enumerate` environment:

```
           \documentclass[]{article}
           \begin{document}

           \begin{enumerate}
            \item Automatic:-\\
            At first a course transformation is applied by the FSI Mapper followed by a fine transformation on the source mesh to move it closer
           \end{enumerate}
           \end{document}
```

Comment: @PratheekHb Sorry I didn't see your comment when I posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

One more way, useful if you need insert normal paragraphs between main items, or you like a more simple coding for a list:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}

\ex. Automatic:
\a.[] At first a course transformation is applied by
the FSI Mapper followed by a fine transformation 
on the source mesh to move it closer

\ex. Manual:
\a. With one finger.
\b. With two fingers.

\end{document}
```